# changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-for-windows

environment：docker for windows 10
version: Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker images: mysql/mysql-server latest
docker had setting shared Drive C:

---

I want to run a mysql container, so I use follow command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -v "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Config":/etc/mysql/ -v "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Data/":/var/lib/mysql/ --name mysqlserver mysql/mysql-server
c2b45a6668746f0aa708b17f05a720ee6b4cff477eeaef714685293d1b60f44b

C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
c2b45a666874        mysql/mysql-server   "/entrypoint.sh my..."   9 seconds ago       Exited (1) 7 seconds ago                       mysqlserver
2de1dbd9880b        redis                "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Exited (0) 4 days ago                          myredis
35c805969295        redis                "docker-entrypoint..."   9 days ago          Exited (0) 9 days ago                          redisServer

C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker logs mysqlserver
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.21-1.1.3
[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

[image: this is the screenshot]

I'm tired，what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `rw` tag while specifying the volume mounts. In your case that would be

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -v "C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/Config":/etc/mysql/:rw -v "C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/Data/":/var/lib/mysql/:rw --name mysqlserver mysql/mysql-server
```

Comment: thanks for your help,when I set dir “C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/Data/” write permission ，it ’s ok! thank you ,very much!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the file `C:/Program Files/MySQL/Data/` on the host mounted as a volume in the container at `/var/lib/mysql/` does not have write permission set.

You can give write permission (`rw`) when you mount `/var/lib/mysql/` by doing

```
-v "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Data/":/var/lib/mysql/:rw
```

instead of

```
-v "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Data/":/var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: @shinercan glad to help, upvote my answer if you think it is useful!